# JavaScript, что означает регулярное выражение /(a)\1+/?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

JavaScript, что означает регулярное выражение /(a)\1+/ ?

https://regex101.com/r/dS8mZ0/1

Как я понял, это выражение аналогично /(a){2,}/, но описание такого (/(a)\1+/) синтаксиса найти не удается.

Comment: **\1** - это ссылка на первую сохранённую группу. В данном случае ***(a)***.  Если мне не изменяет память, таких групп в JS можно сохранять до 9ти.  **P.S:** Если Вы заинтересованы в изучении регулярных выражений, то очень советую ***3-е издание*** книги "**Регулярные выражения**" *(2008г. Джеффри Фридл)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(a)` - группа из `a`
 
`\1` - требование повторить совпадение с первой группой
`\1+` - требование повторить совпадение с первой группой один или более раз

Да, в данном случае выражение эквивалентно такому: `(a){2,}`

Но вот в таком - уже нет: `([ab])\1+` - оно эквивалентно по сути `a{2,}|b{2,}`, хотя получить ту же первую группу в последнем варианте не выйдет.

Для более сложных конструкций эквивалентное выражение будет построить намного сложнее или вообще невозможно.

Answer (score 2):

Может пригодиться небольшая визуализация в дополнение к первому ответу:

```
(a)\1+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/jnzUYB4gV4NYNcOm)